update-manager JSON decoder error
I was trying to update ubuntu from 22.04 to 23.10, but I get the following error when trying to run update-manager:
Unexpected error(s) occurred.
For more details, see the log: /var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log
To file a bug run: ubuntu-bug ubuntu-advantage-tools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 448, in _on_finished
    self._action_done(action,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 365, in _action_done
    self.window_main.start_available()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 241, in start_available
    self.refresh_cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 459, in refresh_cache
    self._get_ua_security_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 285, in _get_ua_security_status
    s = json.load(p.stdout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I found this question with the exact same error, but I don't think I have the same problem as which pro returns user/bin/pro. I'm not very experienced in solving issues like these so I have no idea how to fix this or what the issue even is.
I have tried reinstalling, updating and such but to no avail.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
